# which is first to compute in an expression using mathematical symbols?

Tags: objective-c

I'm recently trying to learn objective-c  . I came from php background.
given this variables

```
int a = 25;
int b = 2;
```

if I do this statement

```
NSLog (@"6 + a / 5 * b = %i", 6 + a / 5 * b);
```

the result is `16`
I tried that in PHP also and was surprised that the output was 16.
Even though I have been doing coding for years already, I always believed in the
MDAS rule, whereby, the computation should be computed in this order 
'multiplication','division','addition','subtraction'.

but..when I follow that rule, the output from the given exmple variables will be

```
8.5
```

now am confused, how to explain this thing?

NOTE: before you even mark this as duplicate. Please read my post and compare it to the other question by some other users. Mine is a very basic one that differentiate it from more advanced questions regarding mathematical symbol precedence that includes too many parenthesis, some obj-c built-in functions that I never heard of before

Comment: It's not MDAS. It's (multiply and divide) then (add and subtract), but within the groups it's *left to right*.

Comment: If you are on OS X, use `man operator` in terminal to show the order or operations and their precedence in C (and Obj-C, C++)

Comment: In mathematics there is no difference between multiplication and division (which is actually a multiplication by inverse number) and between addition and subtraction (which is the addition of the opposite of a number) therefore you cannot really say that multiplication precedes division.

Comment: Just because your example is simpler, doesn't make the answer any different.